# React native framework , I have some problem with my app ,when I try to execute Npm start , help me please

Tags: reactjs, react-native

./node_modules/react-native-reanimated/lib/index.js 4:9
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:9)
File was processed with these loaders:

- C:\Users\Carlos Pungu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure that you added Reanimated plugin to babel.config.js?

```
plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin']
```

more info: https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation#babel-plugin

Comment: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/reanimated#web-support
There's an additional plugin, if you want web-support :)

Answer (score 5):

You can install the npm package. If you already installed it, please try to install it again.

```
npm install react-native-reanimated
```

Answer (score 2):

Installation

```
npx expo install react-native-reanimated
```

after the installation completes, you must also add the Babel plugin to babel.config.js:

```
plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
```